# PostgreSQL Trigger Exception

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4, procedures

I'm having problems with creating this trigger in PostgreSQL 8.4.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tbi_Usuarios() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $tbi_Usuarios$
    BEGIN
        IF trim(both ' ' from NEW.Nombre_usuario) = '' OR NEW.Nombre_usuario IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Debes ingresar un nombre de usuario.';
        END IF;

    IF NEW.Password = '' OR NEW.Password IS NULL THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Debes ingresar una contraseña correctamente';
    ELSE
        NEW.Password := md5(NEW.Password);
    END IF;

    IF Fecha_registro IS NULL THEN
        NEW.Fecha_registro := current_timestamp;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$tbi_Usuarios$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_tbi_Usuarios ON "Usuarios";
CREATE TRIGGER tr_tbi_Usuarios BEFORE INSERT ON "Usuarios"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tbi_Usuarios();
```

The thing is that, when I try to insert a row in the database, the following error shows up:

```
"el registro << new >> no tiene un campo << nombre_usuario >>"
```

or in English:

```
"the table << new >> doesn't have a column << nombre_usuario >>"
```

But in my database, I'm REALLY sure that the columns `Nombre_usuario`, `Password`, `Fecha_registro` exist!

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

You most probably tripped over upper case names. I am not getting tired of advising not to use those.

You probably have a column named

```
"Nombre_usuario"
```

enclosed in double-quotes (`""`) which preserve the mixed case spelling.
But in your trigger function you write:

```
NEW.Nombre_usuario
```

**without double quotes**. Unquoted identifiers are converted to lower case. So this is the same as:

```
NEW.nombre_usuario
```

but not:

```
NEW."Nombre_usuario"
```

Always double-quote mixed case identifiers. Or (much better) exclusively use lower-case identifiers to begin with and save yourself the trouble.
(The identifier for the [`NEW` row in a trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html) is never quoted.)

Further reading:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)
- The chapter ["Identifiers and Key Words"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in the manual